# regular expression for replacing all links but css and js

Tags: php, regex

i want to download a site an replace all links on that site to an internal link.

that's easy:

```
$page=file_get_contents($url);
$local=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$page=preg_replace('/href="(.+?)"/','href="http://'.$local.'?href=\\1"',$page);
```

but i want to exclude all css files and js files from replacing, so i tried:

```
$regex='/href="(.+?(?!(\.js|\.css)))"/';
$page=preg_replace($regex,'href="http://'.$local.'?href=\\1"',$page);
```

but that didnt work,

what am i doing wrong?

i thought

```
?!
```

is a negative lookahead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) question, you need a lookbehind there and better limit the match with a character class:

```
$regex = '/href="([^"]+(?<!\.js|\.css))"/';
```

The charclass first matches the whole link content, then asserts that this didn't end in `.js` or `.css`.
You might want to augment the whole match with `<a\s[^>]*?` even, so it really just finds anything that looks like a link.

Another option would be using [domdocument](/questions/tagged/domdocument) or [querypath](/questions/tagged/querypath) for such tasks, which is usually tedious and more code, but simpler to add programmatic conditions to:

```
htmlqp->find("a") FOREACH $a->attr("href", "http:/...".$a->attr("href"))
// would need a real foreach and an if and stuff..
```